# retrieve meteadata from Revit file

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit, autodesk-bim360

is it possible to retrieve metadata from Revit file stored on BIM 360 OR Forge server using from APIs.
the metadata:

Walls (example: 125)
Ducts (example: 300)
Cable Trays (Example: 43) 
Doors (example: 35)
Structural Columns (example: 0) 
Sheets (example: 12) 
and more....

Comment: Are u developing an application with or without a viewer in place. If you have a viewer in place you can simply query the object tree since its already loaded in. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Most of the Forge getting started tutorials demonstrate this.

The [viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet) goes a step further and extracts all the Revit file properties using the Forge Model Derivative API and saves them in an Excel XLSX spreadsheet.

For more samples, please refer to the [collection of Forge sample code](https://forge.autodesk.com/code-samples).

By the way, as far as I can tell from the sample properties you list, you are not after the metadata, just the standard Revit BIM element properties.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, 
thank you for answering me, but I was thinking if there is a rest Api direct without the viewer.  my plan to write a small script that can run and download the specific metadata from the Revit model.

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve the BIM element properties directly via REST without using the viewer. I repeat what I mentioned above: you are NOT looking for metadata, just element properties. Metadata is something else:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata

Comment: sorry, it's true it the element properties, and i guess this is the API that i can you to retrieve all the model elements properties:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/

really appreciate

Comment: Yes, indeed, you found it. Well done. Thank you for the appreciation.